# Why does my activation function cause NaNs?

Tags: activation-functions

I implemented the following activation function:
$$\sigma(x) = x^{1/3},$$
which returns NaNs after some epochs. I think this is due to the derivative exploding close to $0$. To fix this issue, I implemented a modified activation function:
$$
\sigma'(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
 x, & \text{if } -1 \leq x \leq 1, \\
 x^{1/3}, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Unfortunately, $\sigma'$ suffers from the same issue. Why is that?

Here is my code:

```
def odd_pow(input, exponent):
    return input.sign() * input.abs().pow(exponent)

def custom_activation(x):
    # This will create a mask where values are between -1 and 1
    mask = (x >= -1) & (x <= 1)
    # For values between -1 and 1, apply x
    # For other values, apply x^1/3
    # Use where to combine results based on the mask
    return torch.where(mask, odd_pow(x, 1), odd_pow(x, 1/3))
```

Note: Both ReLU and Tanh don't return NaNs, but I am looking for homogeneous activation functions $\sigma(ax) = g(a)\sigma(x)$.

Comment: Does the derivative cause the NaNs, or the normal activation function?

Comment: @RobinvanHoorn I think the derivative is what is causing the NaNs.

Comment: You need to use a small constant to prevent exploding gradients. Please, see my answer.

Comment: Please look at the gradients being backpropagated to see where the issue comes from.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** the issue is that your `odd_pow()` is *numerically unstable*, and so to fix the exploding gradients, which cause a NaN loss, you simply need to add a small constant when computing the power:

```
def odd_pow(input, exponent, eps=1e-4):
    return input.sign() * (input.abs() + eps).pow(exponent)
```

this ensures that the `pow` is not computed at zero, avoiding NaNs.

---

**Note:** for reference I also keep my old answer, since also the activation $\sigma(x)$ suffers the same problem.

The issue is that the function $\sigma(x) = x^{1/3}$ is zero for $x\le 0$, and so its derivative becomes NaN for negative $x$ and infinity for $x=0$ as shown here:
[image]
where the blue curve is the derivative of $\sigma(x)$, which is depicted in green.

To avoid either NaN or exploding gradients, you need to add a small value (usually called an *epsilon*) to make the computation of the derivative more numerically stable. The following should work:

```
def custom_activation(x, eps=1e-3):
    # set negative values to zero
    tmp = torch.nn.functional.relu(x)
    # add the small epsilon `eps`
    return torch.pow(tmp + eps, exponent=1 / 3.0)
```

Notice that as you lower the `eps`, e.g. at 1e-5, the derivative would be larger. If you really need a small epsilon, then you should also consider to clip the individual gradients (there should be a `clip_grad` functionality related to the optimizer) to ensure stable training.

Comment: The function $\sigma(x) = x^{1/3}$ is not zero for $x \leq 0$—I am taking the real root.

Comment: The zero at $x=0$ is not the issue. It's the derivative is $\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ which is undefined at zero. With their intended $\sigma'$ function, which should simply have derivative of $1$ at $x=0$, the OP looks to have an implementation problem here, not a theoretical one.

Comment: @NeilSlater It could be that torch isn't taking the real roots for the negative values of $x^{-2/3}$.

Comment: @user572780: I would have thought that the `.abs()` would have stopped that issue. I cannot see clearly what is wrong, although I suspect one or more sub-components of your `custom_activation` function is confusing the auto-differentiation.

Comment: @NeilSlater I implemented and tested the code I provide here in Tensorflow, on a simple MNIST classification problem and it trains without any issue

Comment: In TensorFlow? Do you mean PyTorch? Either way, it is *not* the OP's activation function, and there's nothing wrong with the OP's function $\sigma'(x)$ in theory AFAICS.

Comment: There's also nothing wrong with the activation function presented in this answer. However, the *reason* given for the OP's problem in the first sentence is incorrect, and the suggestion to use a different function is also not an answer to the original question.

Comment: @NeilSlater Sorry but I made a bit of confusion here :) As you said, both $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are fine in theory. The issue, in practice, is numerical instability around the zero (I think). I've updated my answer and the issue should be fixed now

Comment: I think you need to take a careful look at OP's definition of $\sigma'(x)$ The function is linear near the origin. You seem to be talking about the OP's first function -  at least a lot of your comments are correct when applied to that

Comment: @NeilSlater Yes, I was referring to the first function, $\sigma(x)$ because as far as I understood $\sigma'$ was a replacement for that, since not working as intended. So I aimed at just fixing $\sigma$